# Why does command binding to a button have different behavior than command binding a menu item?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

Consider the following example with a menu and a button:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
    </Menu>
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste">Paste</Button>
    <TextBox>Content</TextBox>
    <TextBox>Content2</TextBox>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

When I put keyboard focus in one of the text boxes, the TextBox declares that it can handle `ApplicationCommands.Paste`, and so I expect the button and the menu item to enable themselves. What I get instead is that the menu item enables itself, and the button does not. (The button doesn't appear to be "listening" to the `TextBox`' `CommandBinding`)

What's going on here, and is there any way I can work around this?

---

EDIT: I did find this question --> [WPF routed command enabling works with menu but not with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683574/wpf-routed-command-enabling-works-with-menu-but-not-with-a-button?rq=1) <-- but this is not suitable in this case. The button should not be keyboard focusable, and setting it as a focus scope makes it focusable. I can't bind the source, because the actual source needs to be controlled by keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can't use the Command property of a button in this manner unless it's contained in a Toolbar. I get the same results you do with your xaml, but I use the same code regularly to assign this command to a button in a toolbar.

See [Copy and paste commands with WPF buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563666/copy-and-paste-commands-with-wpf-buttons) for more information.

**EDIT:**

You're right. It has to do with the FocusScope, and there are two ways to fix it, as shown here:

[WPF routed command enabling works with menu but not with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683574/wpf-routed-command-enabling-works-with-menu-but-not-with-a-button)

You can set `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` on the button:

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">Paste</Button>
```

Alternately, you can set the button's command target, but this will only work for one textbox.

Comment: If it works in a toolbar, there has to be something ToolBar is doing to enable this which could just as easily be done elsewhere.

Comment: Setting IsFocusScope works in this reduced case but not the general case. Also, it makes the button focusable with the keyboard which is undesirable here.